# What is the purpose of using "Select" multiple times in this LINQ query?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I came across some code like this:

```
Dim results = From item In New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3}
              Select item
              Select item
```

I am surprised that `Select item` twice is legal. It seems to behave exactly the same as if there was only one `Select` line. I tried converting to C# and it produces a compile error.

Is there any reason to use multiple Selects? Could this ever cause the query to behave differently?

Comment: Is Option Strict on or off? Surprised C# would complain while VB allows it since I would have thought they would share the same rules on LINQ.

Comment: @TyCobb: No, they're really quite different in various ways. VB query expressions cover far more of LINQ, and VB allows you to miss off the "Select" part entirely, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the C# equivalent syntax would be :

```
var results = from item in new List<int> {1, 2, 3}
              select item into item
              select item;
```

That way you create a new scope to "chain" queries or quoted from the VB.Net documentation (see links) *The Select clause introduces a new set of range variables for subsequent query clauses* (you can see the into C# keyword [documention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311045.aspx) or the Select VB.Net clause [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384607.aspx) for further information and examples)

Comment: The C# equivalent could also be `var results = new List<int> {1, 2, 3}.Select(x => x).Select(y => y);` if you prefer the lambda syntax (which most people probably do).  Good explanation about introducing a new range variable set, though.

Comment: All answers are good and have my upvote, but this is accepted for linking to the relevant documentation (and teaching me something new about C# too).

Answer (score 4):

I cannot say *why* this is allowed, but by looking at the compiled IL code you'll see that the expression ends up calling `Enumerable.Select` twice.

```
L_0021: ldftn int32 ConsoleApplication1.Module1::_Lambda$__1(int32)
L_0027: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
L_002c: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!1> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Select<int32, int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>)

L_0032: ldftn int32 ConsoleApplication1.Module1::_Lambda$__2(int32)
L_0038: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
L_003d: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!1> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Select<int32, int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>)
```

So in the end, the query is equal to this:

```
Dim results = {1, 2, 3}.Select(Function(i) i).Select(Function(i) i)
```

Comment: Upvoted for showing the IL code and equivalent VB .Net lambda.

Answer (score 3):

The answers from Sehnsucht and Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå are accurate.  The gist of it is that you are using `Select` to generate a result set, then using `Select` again to generate a new result set based on the previous one.  In your example, both result sets are identical, so it is the same as if you only used `Select` once.

To answer your second question, there may be some instances where you want to write your query with more than one `Select` to aid readability or for some other reason.  A trivial example might look like this:

```
Dim results = From item In New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3}
              Where item > 1
              Select item
              Where item < 3
              Select item
```

Which will return a set containing only the integer 2.  Obviously this could be written with one `Select` and one `Where` (using an `And`), but there might be some cases where your conditions are so complex that you want to split them up rather than making them part of a single `Where` clause.  Or there may be other things that you want to do that require splitting the statement up into smaller parts.

Generally speaking, there isn't much use for this sort of thing, but it's nice that LINQ allows it if you have a need.